# VB.NET Interfacing with external DLL to obtain USB names from function

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to interface with a USB device that provides an external C++ dll file and have read a myriad of articles surrounding delegates, marshalling, pointers and I generally get the idea of what is happening. Unfortunately, my practical experience in this area is letting me down in obtaining the final solution.

I have connected to the device in order to create a session successfully but there is a function called EnumDevices which supposedly enumerates the device list for specific future calls. The function has a function within itself that lists the devices and it is this part I am struggling with.

The enumdevices call in the API looks like this:

```
EnumDevices(INTERFACE,FoundDevice,NULL);

bool __stdcall FoundDevice(long data, const char *DeviceName)
{
   printf("device name %s\n", DeviceName)
   Return True
}
```

and according to the documentation, FoundDevice is a call back method called for each found device.

In VB.Net, what I have done is as follows:

Created a delegate function

```
Delegate Function FoundDeviceDelegate(data as integer, DeviceName as PInvoker.Marshal.ByteArrayPtr) as Boolean
```

Then I created a local function with the same signature

```
Private Function FoundDevice(data as integer, DeviceName as PInvoker.Marshal.ByteArrayPtr) as Boolean
   Msgbox(DeviceName.ToString)
   Return True
End Function
```

In my main code, I make the following declarations and calls

```
dim devhandler as assembly.FoundDeviceHandler = AddressOf FoundDevice
dim device as new assembly.FoundDevice(devhandler)
assembly.EnumDevices(INTERFACE,device,vbNull)
```

('assembly' is the reference to the external dll, 'INTERFACE' is a constant and 'device' expects a function with the two parameters - user and devicename)

I thought that the EnumDevices call would then pass back to the device reference which in turns calls the DeviceHandler which references the delegated function which would then output the device name.

What I have got is a pointer value on 'device' but I am struggling referencing this back to a device name. It is never executing the FoundDevice function to show the messagebox.

I have read so much that I think I have read too much surrounding delegates and marshalling etc that I am now struggling to get to the end which feels so close given that I have the pointer reference when I debug it.

If anyone can make sense of the above and provide any useful assistance, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: DeviceName is a `const char*`. Have you tried defining it as `String` in your function?

Comment: Are you interfacing to a 3rd party library? If so can you link to it?

Comment: Dan - unfortunately, it is copyrighted and so I cannot link to it as much as I would like to in order to solve this problem.

Comment: pmcoltrane - I dont think the types are the issue - more so how I am chaining back from EnumDevices call through to the FoundDevice function. But as stranger things have happened, I tried it and it made no difference I'm afraid.

Comment: Hard to guess what kind of animal a PInvoker.Marshal.ByteArrayPtr might be.  Just use String.

Comment: You don't need to declare a delegate in this scenario, as `AddressOf` creates one implicitly.  Also, the constant `vbNull` has a value of 1, whereas the EnumDevices is expecting NULL, which is 0.